# Пакет не найден в модуле

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу достаточно большой проект на Java. Для удобства хочу разбить элементы JavaFX на разные пакеты : Controller, Launcher, Database, Class.
Но достаточно поместить Main метод в пакет, как вылезает ошибка **`Package not found in module`**

Для примера сделал стандартный JavaFX проект :

[image: Project]

module-info.java

```
module com.example.demo.Launcher {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    exports com.example.demo.Controller;
    opens com.example.demo.Controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demo.Launcher;
    opens com.example.demo.Launcher to javafx.fxml;
}
```

HelloController

```
package com.example.demo.Controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

HelloApplication

```
package com.example.demo.Launcher;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй module-info.java перенести в com.example.demo и в ресурсах директория com.example.demo  не обязательна.

Comment: @Митяй, тогда ругается на `Module declaration should be located in a module's source root`